# PowerShell find most recent file

Tags: powershell

I'm new to powershell and scripting in general. Doing lots of reading and testing and this is my first post.
Here is what I am trying to do.  I have a folder that contains sub-folders for each report that runs daily.  A new sub-folder is created each day.
The file names in the sub-folders are the same with only the date changing. 
I want to get a specific file from yesterday's folder.
Here is what I have so far:

```
Get-ChildItem -filter “MBVOutputQueriesReport_C12_Custom.html” -recurse -path D:\BHM\Receive\ | where(get-date).AddDays(-1)
```

Both parts (before and after pipe) work.  But when I combine them it fails.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read output from `get-date | Get-Member -MemberType Property` and then apply [Where-Object docs](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/6a70160b-cf62-48df-ae5b-0a9b173013b4(v=wps.630).aspx):

```
Get-ChildItem -filter “MBVOutputQueriesReport_C12_Custom.html” -recurse -path D:\BHM\Receive\ | `
    Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime.Date -eq (get-date).AddDays(-1).Date}
```

Answer (score 1):

> What am I doing wrong?

```
0,1,2,3,4,5 | Where { $_ -gt 3 }
```

this will compare the incoming number from the pipeline (`$_`) with `3` and allow things that are greater than 3 to get past it - whenever the `$_ -gt 3` test evaluates to $True.

```
0,1,2,3,4,5 | where { $_ }
```

this has nothing to compare against - in this case, it [casts the value to boolean - 'truthy' or 'falsey'](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2006/12/24/boolean-values-and-operators/) and will allow everything 'truthy' to get through. 0 is dropped, the rest are allowed.

```
Get-ChildItem | where Name -eq 'test.txt'
```

without the `{}` is a syntax where it expects `Name` is *a property* of the thing coming through the pipeline (in this case file names) and compares those against 'test.txt' and only allows file objects with that name to go through.

```
Get-ChildItem | where Length
```

In this case, the property it's looking for is Length (the file size) and there is no comparison given, so it's back to doing the "casting to true/false" thing from earlier. This will only show files with some content (non-0 length), and will drop 0 size files, for example.

ok, that brings me to your code:

```
 Get-ChildItem | where(get-date).AddDays(-1)
```

With no `{}` and only one thing given to Where, it's expecting the parameter to be a property name, and is casting the value of that property to true/false to decide what to do. This is saying "filter where *the things in the pipeline have a property named (`"09/08/2016 14:12:06"` (yesterday's date with current time)) and the *value of that property* is 'truthy'". No files have a property called (yesterday's date), so that question reads `$null` for every file, and `Where` drops everything from the pipeline.

You can do as Jimbo answers, and filter comparing *the file's write time* against *yesterday's date*. But if you know the files and folders are named in date order, you can save -recursing through the entire folder tree and looking at everything, because you know what yesterday's file will be called.

Although you didn't say, you could do approaches either like

```
$yesterday = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1).ToString('MM-dd-yyyy')
Get-ChildItem "d:\receive\bhm\$yesterday\MBVOutputQueriesReport_C12_Custom.html"

# (or whatever date pattern gets you directly to that file)
```

or

```
Get-ChildItem | sort -Property CreationTime -Descending | Select -Skip 1 -First 1
```

to get the 'last but one' thing, ordered by reverse created date.

Comment: Excellent explanation. Answers like these are much more helpful than the "here's your one liner" especially for beginners.

Comment: Thank you All for the explanation and advice.  I will keep reading and learning.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
where {$_.lastwritetime.Day -eq ((get-date).AddDays(-1)).Day}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could pipe the results to the `Sort` command, and pipe that to `Select` to just get the first result.

```
Get-ChildItem -filter “MBVOutputQueriesReport_C12_Custom.html” -recurse -path D:\BHM\Receive\ | Sort LastWriteTime -Descending | Select -First 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Can do something like this.

```
$time = (get-date).AddDays(-1).Day
Get-ChildItem -Filter "MBVOutputQueriesReport_C12_Custom.html" -Recurse -Path  D:\BHM\Receive\ | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime.Day -eq $time }
```